# translation for drop down in ts file

Tags: angular

i have translated drop down by using ngif in html page but i want to translate by writing code in ts file

this is what i did in my html page and its translating but want to translate by writing code in component file

{{'abc.'+ node?.Name|translate}} 
              {{node?.Name}}

```
<span *ngIf="node.SpaceType !== 'building' && node.SpaceType !== 'portfolio' && node.SpaceType !== 'meter' && node.SpaceType !== 'facility' && node.SpaceType !== 'floor' && node.SpaceType !== 'points'  else test">{{'abc.'+ node?.Name|translate}}</span> 
              <ng-template #test>{{node?.Name}}</ng-template>
```

i got correct result by doing this but not satisfied with this looking like patchy work

Comment: do you want to use translation, like translating languages? like switching languages in your app?

Comment: Ya and I have created json data for all languages , in that html to page 'abc' which I have used is the json object

Comment: i want to translate in ts file writing function and use that function in html file

Comment: Ican only give u the advice to use ngx-translate for translation. It contains a translationService, that u can inject into the component and retrieve values by key manually

Comment: thanks for your response. can u please tell me how to use it

Comment: i have a two conditions ..                                                                                                  1) i want to translate when commodity == 'Weather' or 'electricity' or 'steam'.       2) i want to convert when spacetype !== 'building' or 'portfolio' or 'meter' or 'points'

Comment: Usually u have a dropdown, choose a language and translate everything. Y these conditions? without further code, your translation json or something else it is difficult to answer ur question properly. regards

Comment: dropdown is coming from dynamic data and i want to translate only when node.commodity is equal to weather electricty steam not all dropdown .